# How do I see state when logging to the console instead of Proxy object inside reducer action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When using `console.log()` inside a reducer action, the state prints as a Proxy object, instead of the object I actually want to see. How do I see the actual object? I am using redux-starter-kit createSlice, I am not sure if this has anything to do with it.

```
import { createSlice } from "redux-starter-kit";

export interface IToDo {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    complete: boolean;
}

const initialState: IToDo[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Read a bit',
        complete: true
    }
];

const { actions, reducer } = createSlice({
    slice: "todos",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        toggleTodo(state: IToDo[], action) {
            const todo = state.find(todo => todo.id === action.payload);
            console.log(todo);
            if (todo) {
                todo.complete = !todo.complete;
            }
        }
    }
})

export const toDosReducer = reducer;
export const { toggleTodo } = actions;
```

This is the output I see in the console when I toggle my ToDo:

[image: Console output]

Comment: have you tried `todo.toJSON()`?

Comment: @SultanH. todo is of type `IToDo` and therefore doesn't have a `toJSON` function.

Comment: @SultanH. you were along the right lines though: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(todo)));` prints the state. This feels massively like overkill however, surely there is an easier way?

Comment: whats wrong with redux dev tool extention? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd

Answer (score 107, accepted):

### Solution

You need to use the `current` function in order to see the actual value of the state.

In your reducer, you can call:

```
console.log(current(state));
```

This `current` function comes from the Immer package which is a dependency of Redux Toolkit.  It is re-exported by Redux Toolkit, so it can be imported from either package:

```
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
```

or

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { current } from 'immer';
```

### Why do I see a `Proxy`?

Redux Toolkit's `createSlice` and `createReducer` helper functions allow you to write reducers where you directly modify the `state` variable.  This can save a lot of code and a lot of headaches compared to writing reducers the traditional way, where you must always return a new state object and cannot mutate any values of your state.

It is okay to "mutate" the `state` variable in a Redux Toolkit reducer because this `state` variable *is not your actual state*.  It is a `Proxy` object.  Specifically, it is a Immer draft.

> The basic idea is that with Immer you will apply all your changes to a temporary *draft*, which is a proxy of the *currentState*. Once all your mutations are completed, Immer will produce the *nextState* based on the mutations to the draft state. This means that you can interact with your data by simply modifying it while keeping all the benefits of immutable data.

For further reading, see:

- [Redux docs - Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)
- [Immer docs - How Immer Works](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/#how-immer-works)
- [MDN web docs - Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

### What is `current()`?

The `current` function is a way to access the current state of the draft object for debugging.  Otherwise, you would see the draft itself which is a `Proxy` and that's not very helpful.  You probably won't ever use `current` for anything other than console logging.

This function is part of the Immer package and it is re-exported by Redux Toolkit specifically for this purpose.

> `current`
>
> The current function from the immer library, which takes a snapshot of the current state of a draft and finalizes it (but without freezing). Current is a great utility to print the current state during debugging, and the output of current can also be safely leaked outside the producer.

For further reading, see:

- [Immer docs: Extracting the current state from a draft](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/current/)
- [Redux Toolkit docs: Exports from Other Libraries](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/other-exports#current)

Comment: Quick note that you need to import current first:

`import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";`

Comment: Why do I get this `Attempted import error: 'current' is not exported from '@reduxjs/toolkit'`

Answer (score 19):

You can convert your object to string with number of indentions, check the code bellow:

```
JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)
```

It returns something like this

```
// { 
//   "firName: "..."
//   "lastName": '...',     
//   ... 
// }
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Now I can stop going mad and pulling my hair out!

Comment: `null` is shorter than `undefined`

Comment: `undefined` has semantic value asserting that value isn't delivered to arguments

Answer (score 2):

```
import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: todosAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    todoToggled(state, action) {
      //ERROR: logs the Proxy-wrapped data
      console.log(state)`
      //CORRECT: logs a plain JS copy of the current data
      console.log(current(state))
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was looking for a way to `console.log()` the redux store, and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))
```