# Why an array is undefined in state React Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

when trying to console.log a piece of (an array) managed with @reduxjs/toolkit it is always either undefined or proxy.

when using `import { original } from "immer";` and `console.log(original(state.theArrayImTryingToLog));`
I simply get: undefined.

when using `console.log(state.theArrayImTryingToLog);`
I get:
0: Proxy
[[Handler]]: null
[[Target]]: null
[[IsRevoked]]: true
length: 1
This is logged when the array initially defined as an empty array or even when I set a dummy object in it.

I read in other posts that this might be an Immer issue, but since I always get undefined / proxy I suspect it might be something else.

Also when `console.log(JSON.stringify(state.theArrayImTryingToLog));` I get the correct array with all of its elements.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getProducts } from "../api/product.api";
import { original } from "immer";

const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: {
    products_in_cart: [],

  },
  reducers: {
       add_to_cart: (state, action) => {
      console.log(state.products_in_cart); -> proxy as above
      console.log(original(state.products_in_cart)); -> undefined
      console.log(JSON.stringify(state.products_in_cart)); -> correct array as string
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm inclined to say that this is just how immer works and not an issue, though the `undefined` is strange.  Do you get the same results using `current` instead of `original`?  Can you create a runnable example on CodeSandbox reproducing this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see state when logging to the console instead of Proxy object inside reducer action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240245/how-do-i-see-state-when-logging-to-the-console-instead-of-proxy-object-inside-re)

Comment: I'm also having same issue, when I print state into console -> console.log(state)
I have this,
[[Handler]]: null
[[Target]]: null
[[IsRevoked]]: true

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue for `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1"`

Comment: By the way for my knowledge you don't need to 'import { original } from "immer";'  because immer is intregrated already into redux-toolkit and is the library that take care of the immutability